# Count and having query

Tags: sql

Please check below table :

```
Id    Code     Name      State       District     Status   
-----------------------------------------------------------
1     10001    ABC       Gujarat     Jamnagar       1
2     10002    BCA       Gujarat     Amreli         0
3     10003    XYZ       NJ          ACX            1
4     10001    VBC       Gujarat     Jamnagar       1
```

I have query below

```
SELECT STATE,
    District,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) Active,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) InActive
FROM TableA
GROUP BY STATE,
    District
```

Now it will return following result to me

```
State   District  Active  InActive
------------------------------------
Gujarat  Jamnagar   0       2
Gujarat  Amreli     1       0
NJ       ACX        0       1
```

But I need to count single row whose `Code` is Same, So it will return `InActive` as 1 for 
`State` `Gujarat` and `District` `Jamnagar` not 2.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: so you mean the count should apply for distinct State and District? check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you distinctly select all columns in a subquery?

```
SELECT STATE,
    District,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) Active,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) InActive
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT STATE,
        District,
        STATUS
    FROM tableA
    ) a
GROUP BY STATE,
    District
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd4b/2)

Answer (score 1):

Rater than `SUM`, select `MAX`, so the values won't aggregate.

Comment: but I can have more than two records .. I need sum of whole the row based on District and State

Comment: @LajjaThaker: `MAX` will also take all records into account. If your set contains `1, 0, 1`, then `MAX` of that set will yield `1`, where `SUM` will yield `2`.