# SQL count duplicate row as single

Tags: sql

I have table

```
ID     State        District        StationCode        Status
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1    Gujarat       Banaskantha      12345               0 
 2    Gujarat       Banaskantha      12345               0
 3    M.P.          Bhopal           22315               1
 4    Gujarat       Banaskantha      12349               0
 5    Gujarat       Banaskantha      12345               1
```

I need result like

```
State      District       Active       InActive
-----------------------------------------------
Gujarat     Banaskantha      2            1
M.P.        Bhopal           0            1
```

Here , `Active`  and `Inactive` fields are sum of `Status` fields based on `0` or `1`

That means here `State` for Gujarat, There `three` times `0` occured , but `two` duplicate rows for `StationCode - 12345`. It means it will be considered as `One`.

I have query like below

```
select distinct 
    state,
    District,
    SUM(
        Case 
        when Status=0 then 1 
        else 0 end
        ) AS Active,
    SUM(
        Case 
            when Status=1 then 1 
            else 0 
        end
        ) AS InActive 
from 
    Station_Master 
group by state, District
```

But I am unable to count duplicate `StationCode` row as Single.

How can I do that ?

Comment: filter the rows in a subquery, check my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count and having query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345670/count-and-having-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would probably address your problem.
I am not 100% sure of the syntax but if you can try it out and let me know if it doesnt work, i can try tweak it for you. The idea is to create a derived table using Group By to eliminate the duplicates that you dont want first and then the outer query is same as your original query - just on the derived table instead.

```
SELECT Distinct 
  X.State, 
  X.District, 
  SUM(Case when X.Status=0 then 1 else 0 end) AS Active,
  SUM(Case when X.Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS InActive
FROM 
  (Select State, District, StationCode, Status
   From Station_Master 
   Group By State,District, StationCode, Status) as X
GROUP BY X.State, X.District
```

Answer (score 5):

you can uniquely filter the rows in a subquery. try,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT state, district,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Active,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InActive
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT state,  district, StationCode, status 
        FROM  Station_Master
    ) a
GROUP BY state, district
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18211/1)

Answer (score 2):

You should use either `DISTINCT` clause or `GROUP BY` clause in sub-query before fetch data from it:

Using `DISTINCT` clause:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT state, district,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Active,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InActive
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT state,  district, StationCode, status 
        FROM  Station_Master
     ) A
GROUP BY state, district;
```

Using `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    state,
    District,
    SUM(Case when Status=0 then 1 else 0 end) AS Active,
    SUM(Case when Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS InActive 
FROM
(
    SELECT state,District,StationCode,Status
    FROM Station_Master 
    GROUP BY state, District, Stationcode,Status
) A
GROUP BY state, District;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18211/12)

I also added few records in table to check the query in [this SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b5b8/2) And worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Below SQL:

```
declare @temptable table 
(
Id int,
state nvarchar(250),
District nvarchar(250),
StationCode nvarchar(250),
Status bit
)
Insert into @temptable values  (1,'Gujarat','Banaskantha','12345',0 )
Insert into @temptable values  (2,'Gujarat','Banaskantha','12345',0 )
Insert into @temptable values  (3,'M.P.','Bhopal','22315',1 )
Insert into @temptable values  (4,'Gujarat','Banaskantha','12349',0 )
Insert into @temptable values  (5,'Gujarat','Banaskantha','12345',1 )

select  tbl.state,tbl.District,SUM(cast(tbl.Status as int)) as Active ,(Count(*) -   
    SUM(cast(tbl.Status as int))) as InActive  
from (select distinct state,District,StationCode,Status from @temptable)as tbl 
group by tbl.state,tbl.District
```

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve the distinct tuples of (State, District, Status) and then run your aggregation query on top of it, like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.state,
    a.District,
    SUM(
        Case 
        when a.Status=0 then 1 
        else 0 end
        ) AS Active,
    SUM(
        Case 
            when a.Status=1 then 1 
            else 0 
        end
        ) AS InActive 
from 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            state, 
            district, 
            status 
        FROM 
            Station_Master 
    ) as a
group by a.state, a.District
```

Comment: It will be return "Active" column as for District Gujarat and Taluka Banaskantha , but I need 2 because Gujarat State having 3 active count but there are two rows which having same station code so it will be considered as one, so it will return as 2.